# postgresql array_length in dynamic watch

Tags: sql, массивы, postgresql

Postresql DB 9.* . Я хочу получить из:

**from**

```
time | value   | 
-----+---------+
  1  |    A    |
  2  |    A    |
  3  |    A    |
  4  |    B    |  
  5  |    B    |
```

**this**

```
time | value   | length |  buf_1  | buf_2 |
-----+---------+--------+---------+-------+
  1  |    A    |   1    |    A    |   A   |
  2  |    A    |   1    |   A,A   |   A   |
  3  |    A    |   1    |  A,A,A  |   A   | 
  4  |    B    |   2    |A,A,A,B  |  A,B  |
  5  |    B    |   2    |A,A,A,B,B|  A,B  |
```

где столбец длина, как мне кажется, считается примерно так:

```
array_length(array_agg(distinct(values)), 1)
```

но это мне выведет для всех значений конечную длину, а я хочу, чтобы длина записывалась динамически для упорядоченных по времени значений
или, по крайней мере, получить **время когда value меняется с A на B, т.е. здесь time = 4**
Спасибо!

Comment: write russian please

Comment: Не понимаю, вам нужна именно колонка с массивом значений "накопившихся" в этой строке или просто число, которое увеличивается когда меняется значение

Comment: нужна колонка length, а по факту значение time когда length каждый раз становиться  больше на единицу

Comment: Но у вас в исходных данных я вижу только единичные символы, никаких значений нет. Я так понял вы их пытаетесь собрать в массив что бы получить длину этого массива. Но то же самое вам даст функция rank()

Comment: вот, может быть, я же не особо знаю sql) поэтому я думал сделать через 'select rank() over(partition by smth)' но я вот не знал по чему разделять, так чтобы 'rank()' A,B был как в колонке length. И , соответственно, мог бы вытащить значение **time**, где length (rank()) == 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то что то вроде этого:

```
with TableX as(
 select * from ( values (1,'A'),(2,'A'),(3,'A'),(4,'B'),(5,'B') ) X(time, value)
)

select time, value, sum(Change) over(order by time)+1
 from (
  select *, case when value <> lag(value) over(order by time) then 1 else 0 end as Change
    from TableX
 ) A
```

В внутреннем запросе функция `lag()` получает значение поля из предыдущей записи в заданной сортировке. И на основе этого `case` выдает 1 для строк, где значение изменилось. Если вам в итоге нужны только эти строки, то можете добавить в внешнем запросе условие `where Change=1`. На всякий случай привел получение поля типа вашего *length* просуммировав признаки изменения.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!)